# I need to press the clickpad of my Dell XPS 13 very strongly for a click

Tags: drivers, dell-xps, synaptics-touchpad

since a few weeks, my touchpad has gotten unusable. First I thought an update messed up the Synaptics driver config. But then I realized that the config works. It's just that I have to press the touchpad strongly to get a click registered.

Tap to click works, but I'm talking about pushing down the whole touchpad and triggering the integrated button underneath. When I press the touchpad, I can hear the click. But I have to keep pressing stronger to trigger a click.

Is there a driver setting for this or is this a hardware defect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hardware defect. There is a mechanical metal membrane switch under the touchpad and the membrane is likely cracked or worn out.